# How can I log only the INFO level in Log4perl?

Tags: perl, log4perl

log4perl has a threshold option in the configuration file that will log all calls that level or higher. Is there an option of setting it log only one type of call?  I want to only log calls of level "INFO".

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can do it using a [Log4Perl Filter](http://log4perl.sourceforge.net/releases/Log-Log4perl/docs/html/Log/Log4perl/Filter.html). Use the `LevelToMatch` property to define which exact level needs to be matched.